# Unwanted unique constraint when using @ManyToMany JPA annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using spring-boot / spring-data-jpa for my project. Entities below will create tables in oracle when spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is set to update.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCENARIO")
public class Scenario {

    private Integer worksetId;
    private Integer ruleSetId;
    private Set<Rule> rules;

    @Id
    public Integer getWorksetId() {
        return worksetId;
    }

    public void setWorksetId(Integer worksetId) {
        this.worksetId = worksetId;
    }

    @Column(name = "RULE_SET_ID")
    public Integer getRuleSetId() {
        return ruleSetId;
    }

    public void setRuleSetId(Integer ruleSetId) {
        this.ruleSetId = ruleSetId;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "RULE_SET", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WORKSET_ID", referencedColumnName = "RULE_SET_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RULE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    public Set<Rule> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }

    public void setRules(Set<Rule> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "RULE")
public class Rule {
    private Integer id;
    private String description;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

What I'm expecting is pretty straightforward that SCENARIO / RULE table will be created, as well as a mapping table named RULE_SET. Everything goes well except that an unwanted unique constraint on RULE_SET_ID in table SCENARIO is created but obviously same RULE_SET_ID should be able to be shared by several scenarios. Could anyone kindly help? Much appreciated!!

BTW, I'm using spring-boot 1.4.0 with hibernate 5.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, if you do `referencedColumnName = "RULE_SET_ID"`, `RULE_SET_ID` — should be unique.

You can use a surrogate key for `Scenario`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCENARIO")
public class Scenario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

}
```

and use a `@ManyToMany` mapping

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "RULE_SET", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WORKSET_ID"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RULE_ID"))
public Set<Rule> getRules() {
    return rules;
}
```

**Update**

I would like to use `RuleSet` entity for a set of rules (with a maping using a join table):

```
@Entity
class RuleSet {

  @OneToMany
  private List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! However, the logic is, I have several rules grouped with rule_set_id and the same rule_set_id can be used in different scenario. With this being said, rule_set_id in scenario should not be unique in scenario table. Or I'm using @ManyToMany improperly?

Comment: That's probably the only workaround for the time being. Many thanks!

Comment: @RogerZhong You are welcome. I don't understand your task properly, but I think It is not a temporaly workaround — it is a valid approach to the database schema.